# preserve color when executing child_process.spawn

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to execute a windows command through cmd.exe in node.js using child_process.spawn. It executes correctly, but only displays in default text color. How do I preserver the color. Is it possible?

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    cmd    = spawn('cmd', ['/s', '/c', 'C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\MSBuild c:\\test.sln']);

cmd.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    process.stdout.write(data);
});

cmd.stderr.on('data', function(data){
    process.stderr.write(data);
});

cmd.on('exit', function(code){
    console.log(code);
});
```

When executing via node, the color is not preserved.
[image: Executing via node.js]

When executing via cmd.exe directly, the color is present. (This is the expected behavior). How do I get this behvior when executing via node.
[image: When executing through cmd.exe]

Comment: +1 for the simple, executable example, and the nice screenshots explaining the now and later. Nice!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
  , command = 'C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\MSBuild c:\\test.sln'
  , cmd    = spawn('cmd', ['/s', '/c', command], { customFds: [0,1,2] });

cmd.on('exit', function(code){
    console.log(code);
});
```

Note that I'm not positive whether or not `customFds` works on Windows. I know that it's old deprecated functionality doesn't work, but when only passing `[0,1,2]` as the fd's, I think there is a special case for that.

I've been doing [something similar here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-weak/blob/1cf1ff4909ddf959218501ecd6ad58d53766de04/build.js#L13-15), but I've only ran that command on Unix machines. So let me know if that works on Windows.

Comment: Since `customFds` is deprecated, is there a way to do this without `customFds` on Unix machines as well?

Comment: @JPRichardson Unfortunately there is no other way to do it without the deprecated `customFds`. I don't believe it is going anywhere anytime soon, especially for this use-case.

Comment: As a side note @prabir, I'm assuming you are attempting to compile a native addon for node. You should definitely checkout [node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) and use that, it will make life easier :)

Comment: As a side note, anybody wanting this functionality for real should upvote this: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2754

Comment: This doesn't work for me using just `ls` under ubuntu bash

Answer (score 173):

There are new 'stdio' option for child_process.spawn(). Try following:

```
spawn("path to executable", ["params"], {stdio: "inherit"});
```

"Inherit" means [0, 1, 2] or [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr].

Comment: +1 Great solution, without using deprecated functionality. Definitely the winning answer in my opinion.

Comment: Works great! Note: event funcs like `spawnedThing.stdout.on` and `spawnedThing.stderr.on` will no longer exist since it's inheriting the write streams from its parent. Took me a little while to realize this while I was getting this error message: `Cannot call method 'on' of null`

Comment: I have a problem related to what Chris mentions - I want to add some custom text to each line of output, so I need the 'on' functions, but since they are now gone, how can I preserve the original output color and prepend something to each line of the output?

Comment: Works for me under Windows too.

Comment: For those with the `Cannot call method 'on' of null` errors... when you set `stdio` to inherit you can then use `process.stdout.on` as in the parent process the child process is inheriting stdio from.

Comment: This works great for me running appium tests with node, creating mocha as a child process.  Working on a mac with ES6.  Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 30):

If you are getting error:

> Cannot call method 'on' of null

Try this:

```
spawn("command", ["args"], { env: { ...process.env, FORCE_COLOR: true } });
```

works with mocha

Comment: If you receive the error "spawn node ENOENT", this variation worked for me: `process.env.FORCE_COLOR = true; spawn("command", ["args"], { env: process.env });`

Comment: You are a legend

Comment: This is the only answer that fixed the problem for me, thanks!

Comment: Riffing off @KevinReilly, I did `{ env: { ...process.env, FORCE_COLOR: true } }` to make it a one-liner.

Comment: This one liner works in both ubuntu and windows. I tested it in both. @Prabir please make this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 25):

crossplatform solution that worked for me was to use both `shell: true` and `stdio: 'inherit'`:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const childProcess = spawn('node', ['./child.js'], { shell: true, stdio: 'inherit' });
```

`shell: true` does not seem to still be relevant with Node 21. this answer was originally written for node 0.4.7 or something

`stdio: 'inherit'` also takes an array [Stdin, Stdout, Stderr] where you can specify 'inherit', or 'pipe', and others. see the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#optionsstdio

⚠️ There is a catch. If you need to listen to `childProcess.stdout.on('data', ...)`. It won't work when stdio is set to 'inherit' because node then set stdout to null. To go around this limitation you need to pipe manually the outputs

```
let output = '';
const childProcess = spawn('node', ['./child.js']);

childProcess.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
childProcess.stdout.on('data',  (data) => {
  output += data.toString();
});
childProcess.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
childProcess.on('exit', () => {
  console.log(output);
});
```

Comment: This would work but how would you tell which log is from which child process? Using `inherit` will make child process log behaves like parent process log.

Comment: my goal was to display logs as they arrived in the console. Like we could see in a jenkins build console. In my case I didn't care about differentiating which log come from where. Using the solution I used was the only that fitted my need. By the way, a solution to do log properly I recommand is bunyan. winston is great too but bunyan is lighter

Comment: awesome, just what I needed!

Comment: `shell: true` was unnecessary in my case to preserve colored output, just `stdio: 'inherit'` is enough.

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't fix the underlying issue (lack of a proper TTY stream) but it should help get around it.

If the sub-process you're running uses supports-color (https://www.npmjs.com/package/supports-color) like chalk, then you can set an environmental variable `FORCE_COLOR` to any value and it will skip the rest of the checks.  This will allow you to continue to use pipes (and capture/modify the returned data) unlike the `inherit` fix.

There is also a node-pty (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pty) module that provides a `.spawn` with the ability to pass a pty (pseudo tty) that may be a more holistic answer.  I haven't played with it yet, and I'm not sure if it's cross platform or not.

Comment: I can confirm this works and enables retaining the colors while being able to capture and modify `stdout`. Btw, I set the environmental variable simply by passing it to `spawn` option `env`, easy peasy!

Comment: Somehow I am missing something. I tried this, but still when I do:

process.env.FORCE_COLOR = 'true';
const proc = execa('npm', ['outdated'], { cwd: dir, stdout: 'pipe', reject: false, env: process.env });
proc.stdout?.pipe(process.stdout);

colors do not work, but if I put stdout: process.stdout (and remove the .pipe), colors shows. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried many options above, and they did not work. For npm (and probably node) commands, this works:

```
const ps = _spawn('npm', ['outdated', '--color=always'], { stdio: 'pipe'});
ps.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
// Then, you can also ps.stdout.on('data',...) for further processing
```

The trick is the `--color=always` (using Mac OSX with zsh). I did not need to do the FORCE_COLOR.

However, that does not work for all commands, for example `ls` does not seem to accept this argument.

Comment: This worked for me when using chalk and passing the output through a spawn

Answer (score 1):

If you want to either keep the color or add some notation for the output, you can try the code below:

```
const {spawn} = require('node:child_process')
const {Writable} = require('node:stream')
const cmd = spawn(
    'cmd',
    [
        '/s',
        '/c',
        'C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\MSBuild c:\\test.sln',
    ],
    {stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, 'pipe']}
)
const error = new Writable()
error._write = function (data, ...argv) {
    console.log('your notation')
    process.stderr._write(data, ...argv)
}
error.stderr.pipe(customStream)
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was there too. Like said in the thread, there's no colored output because the command you're executing doesn't detect a TTY environment.
If you:

- Don't want to inherit the child stdout
- Don't know which command is going to be executed (then you don't know which of e.g --ansi or --colors can work)

Then you should spawn a PTY from node. You may use `node-pty`, but it is a hassle to install, and it doesn't support latest node versions. Instead, I suggest using [this node package](https://github.com/CyriacBr/get-pty-output) that I wrote.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy. Also, this is your 3rd recent answer linking to the package, and that's bordering on excessive self-promotion even with disclosure.

Comment: Got it. I was trying to give as much exposure as possible to let others know a solution exists, so that they do not despair like I did. But I will be careful from now on.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve colours in stdout/stderr stream don't spawn the application directly, rather using `unbuffer` tool (on linux you might need to run `apt install expect`)

```js
let app = "command to run";
let args = ["--array", "--of", "--arguments"];
var child = cp.spawn("unbuffer", [app, ...args], {cwd:tempPath()});

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  process.stdout.write('stdout: ' + data);
});

child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  process.stdout.write('stderr: ' + data);
});

child.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Child process`s stdout is not a TTY

I'm facing a similar issue

```
// main
const child = spawn('node', ['./child.js'], { stdio: 0, 'pipe', 2 });
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

// child
console.log(process.stdout.isTTY); // undefined
console.log(123); // no color
console.log('\u001b[1;34mhello\u001b[0m'); // color preserved
```

Only the third console will display color, and `isTTY` is undefined.
I tried `node-pty`, but that will lost IPC support.
So I tried to replace the global console instance:

```
// main
const child = spawn('node', ['./child.js'], { stdio: 0, 'pipe', 2 });
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

// child
const { Console } = require('console'); // node>=8
global.console = new Console({
  stdout: process.stdout,
  stderr: process.stderr,
  colorMode: true,
});
console.log(process.stdout.isTTY); // undefined
console.log(123); // color preserved
console.log('\u001b[1;34mhello\u001b[0m'); // color preserved
```

Comment: So in the end, did your code work? It’s not clear from your wording.

Comment: @tdy Sorry for my bad English.
I wrote a demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-darkness-u9xnht

Comment: Texts need to be wrapped with ANSI escape codes before writing to `process.stdout`.
In nodejs, the global console instance will do this job automatically by detecting `process.stdout.isTTY` property, if true, `console.log(true)` means `process.stdout.write("\u001b[1;33mtrue\u001b[0m\n")`, otherwise it equals `process.stdout.write("true\n")`.

Comment: Whether the child process runs within a TTY context or not depends on the `stdio` option. I'm using `stdio: 'pipe'`, and the `process.stdout.isTTY` is false in the child process, so I replace it global console instance to force it to wrap the text with color escape codes before writing to its `process.stdout`.

Comment: Not all tools detect TTY environment, some rely on environment variables or something else.