# Display running child process' output in nodejs (windows)

Tags: node.js, exec, child-process

For example sake, I'm running the most basic webServer in node (I'm using windows) with the following code (named server.js):

```
    var http = require('http');
       http.createServer(function (req, res) {
         res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
         res.end('Hello World\n');
       }).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

I would like to run this as a child process, and am successfully doing so with the following:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var serv = exec('node server.js', function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('outputs & errors:' + error, stdout, stderr);
});
```

However, I receive nothing once I run the second file.  No "outputs & errors", no "Server running at...".  If I type localhost:1337 in a browser, I get "hello world" though, so I know it's running.  Is there a way to pipe that "server running..." so I can be "sure" it's listening?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Exec will return `STDOUT` and `STDERR` when the child finishes, see **[`exec`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)**. That's why you do not see any output, when the server starts.

What you want is **[`fork`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)**, which automatically connects the child process `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to your parent's. This is the preferred way if your child process is a node process.

If you want to use exec you can use the child processe's streams to get your data, e.g.:

```
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

Comment: Fantastic.  I had looked at spawn, but neglected to look at Fork, which appears to be exactly what I need.

Comment: Is it possible to get the coloring working when streaming the child stdout? For example I'm executing another gulp command which normally has a nice colored output but when the two pipes are connected the output from the child gulp appears all as white chars loosing the coloring.

Comment: I found the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725809/preserve-color-when-executing-child-process-spawn

Answer (score 2):

```
var child_process = nw.require('child_process');
var spawn = child_process
```

//The following is on windows and I record stdout and stderr to my logger

```
var proc = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/S', '/C', script_path]);
proc.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
       logger(logtag, 'proc_stdout: ' + data);
});

proc.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    logger(logtag, 'proc_stderr: ' + data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just specify that you want the child process to inherit stdio of parent one:

```
require('child_process').exec('node server.js', { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

Comment: Presently (node v17) the stdio option doesn't seem to be supported by exec, only fork.