# Preserve color codes when exec-ing

Tags: bash, colors, go

As part of a larger program, I'm making a call to grep, and outputting its results to standard out:

```
// execute grep command
cmd := exec.Command(GREP_BIN_PATH, argArray...)
stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

err = cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
go io.Copy(os.Stdout, stdout)
go io.Copy(os.Stderr, stderr)
cmd.Wait()
```

If I make an identical call to grep directly from the terminal, grep outputs multi-color text (eg., highlighting in red any match in its output).  Doing a little research, it seems as though there are special [ansi color codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) that grep/other programs use to change color highlighting.

Where do these colors go when I exec a command from go?  Is there any way that I can exec from within go to preserve ansi color codes and just copy the output from grep to standard out (similar to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725809/preserve-color-when-executing-child-process-spawn), but for go)?

(I also know that I could manually re-insert color codes.  But that seems painful, and I'd rather just pipe grep's original colors.)

Please let me know if something in the question is unclear/needs clarification.  Thanks!

Comment: `$ man grep` and search for color.

Comment: I wish someone posted an answer specific to Go and not specific to grep for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`grep` and most other color-using tools detect whether they are sending output to a terminal or not when they decide whether to use color.

Files and pipes, etc. often don't want the color codes and don't know what to do with them.

You can force `grep` to output colors anyway with the `--color=always` flag though.

Comment: Just to quickly expand on this response.  Looking through the grep source code, it appears that the way that grep detects whether it sends output to a terminal or not is to check the TERM environment variable.  (See https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-TERM-variable.html)  Presumably, exec-ing with this environment variable set would also fix the problem.  (Although, I have not yet explicitly checked.)

Comment: I would assume it also checks with `isatty` or similar calls but possibly not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Etan.  I checked the source: it does use ``isatty`` as well.  Further, it requires ``isatty`` to return true (for stdout) *and* the TERM environment variable to be set (and not equal to "dumb.")  As a result, I don't think my solution above of just passing an additional TERM env variable through to exec would work: the isatty condition might still return false.