# NodeJS child_process: close event not fired when specifying stdio: "inherit"

Tags: node.js, child-process, stdio

I am trying to execute some commands in the shell using NodeJS. Therefore I use the `node:child_process` module.

I use the `spawn` function in order to be able to forward the output of the child process to the console of the main process.
In order to keep the formatting of the output of the child process I passed the option `stdio: "inherit"` (as described in this question: [preserve color when executing child_process.spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725809/preserve-color-when-executing-child-process-spawn)).

But if I add this option the child process events (exit, disconnect, close, ...) don't work anymore. If I get rid of the option I lose the formatting, but the events work. Is there a way to keep the formatting and be informed, when the child process closes?

The (relevant) code:

```
const { spawn } = require("node:child_process");

let child = spawn("yarn", args, {
  stdio: "inherit",
  shell: true,
});
child.on("close", (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`stdio: 'inherit'` means you're also forwarding your STDIN to the child process, therefore if the child process reads STDIN, it will never exit, and your `close` listener will never be called. In particular, that's the case for Node.JS REPL (`yarn node`).

Depending on your needs, you may want to:

1. just stop the child process with `child.kill()`. The `close` listener is then called, note that `code` is 0, and the second argument (`signal`) is `SIGTERM` ([documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#event-close));
2. do not forward STDIN but still forward STDOUT and STDERR back: call `spawn` with `stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit']` ([documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio)). When the child process will exit by itself and the streams released, the `close` listener will be called.

Comment: These solutions don't work for me. I can't use the first one because the child process needs to finish, I can't just kill it. If I use the second one the close event still isn't fired.

Comment: Then please give the whole args you're using, as well as a minimal script which emulates the one you're launching, if any. It may be the case that this script is somehow wrong and does not release the streams, therefore the parent process never triggers the `close` event.

Comment: My args in the above script are:  [
  "create",
  "next-app",
  "test",
  "&&",
  "cd",
  "test",
  "&&",
  "yarn",
  "add",
  "styled-components",
  "next-i18next",
  "next-seo",
  "&&",
  "yarn",
  "add",
  "--dev",
  "eslint-config-prettier",
  "lint-staged",
  "prettier",
  "&&",
  "npx",
  "husky-init",
];

Comment: Ha that's the problem. You're giving all these args to a single process `yarn`, but Yarn doesn't know how to handle `&& ...`. What you meant is to run several processes. So instead, split every step into its own call to `spawn`, and chain them, either through the callbacks or using Promises.